Issue with useNavigate and useBlocker in createBrowserRouter Setup
App.tsx
const createRouter = (user: User | null, isChair: boolean) =>
  createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: pagePaths.home,
      element: user === null ? <Login /> : isChair ? <PatientList /> : <Navigate to={pagePaths.management} />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    },
  ...
]);

function App() {
  const [showDuplicationLoginModal, setShowDuplicationLoginModal] = useState(false);

  const handleDuplicationLogin = () => {
    setShowDuplicationLoginModal(true);
  };

  const user = useUser();

  const isChair = useMemo(() => user !== null && user.role === 'chair', [user]);

    const router = useMemo(() => createRouter(user, isChair), [user, isChair]);

  return (
          <GlobalModalProvider>
            {showDuplicationLoginModal && <DuplicationLoginModal />}
            <ToastContainer />
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
          </GlobalModalProvider>
  );
}

GlobalModal.tsx
export const GlobalModalProvider = (props: Props) => {
  const [modalQueue, setModalQueue] = useState<ModalQueueItem[]>([]);

  const addModal = (modal: ModalQueueItem) => {
    setModalQueue([...modalQueue, modal]);
  };

  const removeModal = () => {
    setModalQueue(modalQueue.slice(1));
  };

  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={{ modalQueue, addModal, removeModal }}>
      {props.children}

      {modalQueue[0] ? <GlobalModalSelector type={modalQueue[0].type} props={modalQueue[0].props} /> : null}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
};

const GlobalModalSelector = (modal: ModalQueueItem) => {
  switch (modal.type) {
    case ModalType.LOGOUT:
      return <SettingLogout {...(modal.props as SettingLogoutProps)} />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
};

export const useGlobalModal = () => {
  return useContext(ModalContext);
};


SettingLogout.tsx
export interface SettingLogoutProps {
  toggle: () => void;
}

const SettingLogout = ({ toggle }: SettingLogoutProps) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      navigate(pagePaths.home);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <ModalLayout>
      <SmallConfirmModal
        headerText={t('logout_confirm')}
        firstButton={t('no')}
        secondButton={t('yes')}
        onSecondClick={handleLogout}
        type="viewer"
        onFirstClick={toggle}
      />
    </ModalLayout>
  );
};

export default SettingLogout;


I changed from BrowserRouter to createBrowserRouter to use useBlocker, but now I'm getting the error:
useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component

Upon investigation, it seems that the issue is with useNavigate() being used inside a Modal component within GlobalModalProvider in App.tsx, where I'm managing the modal with GlobalContext.
I need to use both useBlocker and Global Modal. How should I modify my code to resolve this issue?

Where is any useNavigate being used in the code you have shared? Please [edit] to clarify the issue or problem and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

Also, just FYI, you will want to create the router outside the ReactTree so it's not re-created each time the component rerenders for any reason, remounting all your routes and routed components.

Thank you. @DrewReese.  I modified the code to create the router outside of the App() function. Additionally, I added the code where useNavigate is used.

Update GlobalModalProvider to be a layout route component in your router and render it within the RouterProvider so it can use the useNavigate hook and any other hooks/components/etc that depend on the routing context. The marked duplicate shows how.
